# Logic behind the loading external XML file ino Database

Tags: oracle, xmltype

Hi I am new to XML file handling in Oracle.  I was lookig at a code which loads XML into a database column from an external file. I have some doubts .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY xml_dir AS 'c:temp';

CREATE TABLE xml_tab (
  id        NUMBER(10),
  filename  VARCHAR2(100),
  xml       XMLTYPE
)
/

ALTER TABLE xml_tab ADD (
  CONSTRAINT xml_tab_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
/

CREATE SEQUENCE xml_tab_seq;



    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE load_xml (p_dir       IN  VARCHAR2,
                                      p_filename  IN  VARCHAR2) AS
  l_bfile  BFILE := BFILENAME(p_dir, p_filename);
  l_clob   CLOB;
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (l_clob, TRUE);       
  DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);  
  DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(l_clob, l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_bfile));
  DBMS_LOB.fileclose(l_bfile);

  INSERT INTO xml_tab (
    id,
    filename,
    xml
  )
  VALUES (
    xml_tab_seq.NEXTVAL,
    p_filename,
    XMLTYPE.createXML(l_clob)
  );
  COMMIT;
  
  DBMS_LOB.freetemporary (l_clob);
END;
/
```

Doubts-

1. Is it necessary to do it? What's the purpose?**DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (l_clob,TRUE)**
2. Instead of doing XMLTYPE.CreateXML(l_clob) can we do XMLTYPE(l_clob)?  What's the difference between this two ?

   I know these are basic question but I am trying to understand the root cause.

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Comment: I took it from oracle base.

Comment: Do you have a link to the original page?

Comment: Please search on Oracle base. Type XML type

Comment: Thanks. Which version of Oracle?